# How to share a server context between packages

Tags: go, go-fiber

I am very new to go and fiber and am struggling with creating a server in a package and then sharing the context in another package.

```
// package main
func init() {
    // Init server
    globs.InitServer()
}

func main() {
    globs.Server.Get("/hello", handlers.HelloWorld)
}
```

and I am initializing the server as;

```
// package globs
// global vars
var (
    Conf   map[string]string
    DBPool *pgxpool.Pool
    Loggi  *zap.Logger
    Server *fiber.App
)

func InitServer() {
    srv := fiber.New()
    srv.Use(logger.New())
    Server = srv
    Server.Listen(":3000")
}
```

Finally, I am trying handle the controllers as;

```
// package handlers
func HelloWorld(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    globs.Loggi.Info("Says Hello")
    return c.SendString("Hello, World !")
}
```

I am not getting any error during compilation and the app starts fine, but it is not recognising any routes. If i goto "/hello", it gives a 404 and show "Cannot GET /hello"

Comment: I'm not familiar with fiber, but `Server.Listen` usually does not return. Move that call to the last part of main, after you setup everything.

Comment: Thank you. That actually fixed the issue. Can you add you answer so I can mark it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `Server.Listen` in the `init` function. `Server.Listen` does not return until listening fails, so you have to move that to the end of main, after you setup everything.